# ListView Item index

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How can we get the DoubleClicked item (index) from a ListView?

```
 private void listViewModels_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {
      //This line doesn't work
      int i = listViewModels.SelectedItem ();             
      string mdl_path=GetCurrentItemPath(i);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SelectedItem` isn't a function, try

```
ListViewItem item = listViewModels.SelectedItems[0];
```

Comment: Your 0 is what I am trying to get from when I double click the listView.

Comment: No it's not, the 0 is the first item in the selected array, which will be of length 1 when you double click one, you can get the index of the selected item by `item.Index`

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to get?

If you want to get the selected index:

```
listBox1.SelectedIndex
```

If you want to get the `ListViewItem`:

```
listBox1.Items[listBox1.SelectedIndex];
```

If you want to get the value of the selected item:

```
listBox1.SelectedValue;
```

If you want to get the text of the selected item:

```
listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Answer (score -3):

You'd generally want to use the ListView.GetItemAt(int x, int y) function:

```
void listView1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
        listView1.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y);
}
```